# Solving for complex Eigen Values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to find an eigen vector given $ \lambda = 1+i$:

Given:

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$

$A- \lambda I = \begin{pmatrix} -i & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & -i & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1-i\end{pmatrix}$

I know that $-ix - y + z = 0$

However, how should I solve for or get rid of the 'i' in the equation? Do I need to use the complex conjugate for this?

Comment: Please format you post using MathJax. If you don't know how to use it, a quick reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Is this proper formatting now? Or do I need to format the -ix-y+z=0 equation?

Comment: To find an eigenvector, it suffices to "guess" the solution $x=i,y=1,z=0$

Comment: I mean, just from looking at it, I can see $\begin{pmatrix} i \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector

Comment: And the actual answer is solve the system of linear equations. E.g. use Gaussian elimination or something.

Comment: @APorter1031 It's not necessarily to format $-ix-y+z=0$ with MathJax. However, it looks way better, might attract more users and is helpful for other people, who want to recreate the problem later.

Comment: @jgon how? Did you let z = 0 and solve? What's the thought process behind this

Comment: @APorter1031 well just from looking at it I could see that the left two columns were linearly dependent. If I multiplied the left column by $i$ it would equal minus the right column. Hence I knew what the eigenvector should be. It isn't an algorithm tho. The algorithm is gaussian elimination, or however you solve linear equations.

Comment: You've written down the equation that you get from the first row of the matrix.   You get two more equations from the other two rows.  It's just a system of 3 linear equations in 3 unknowns.

Comment: Why do you think that you need to eliminate $i$? This eigenvalue has no real eigenvectors.

Comment: @amd I guess I am just struggling with the concept of complex numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only stated the first equation for the eigenvector

$$
-i x - y + z = 0\\
$$

There are also the other 2

$$
x - i y + z = 0\\
0 x + 0 y + (1-i) z = 0
$$

The last equation tells you $z=0$ by dividing by $1-i$. What's left?

$$
-i x - y =0\\
x - i y = 0
$$

Multiply the second by $-i$

$$
- i x - y = 0\\
$$

so you get nothing new from that. Just give a solution to the first. Suppose $x=1$ then $y = - ix=-i$ so together you get $(1,-i,0)$ as the eigenvector. Rescaling $x$ just rescales the entire vector.